# Counting sort segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50, counting-sort

Below is my attempt at a counting sort. I have diagrammed my logic, run through it verbally, and commented my code thoroughly. However, my code causes a segmentation fault. I understand a segmentation fault represents an illegal access to memory, so this must mean one of my index values is trying to access an index outside of an array's range. However, I can't figure out why this is happening.

Fortunately, my debugger highlights the line below, which I've also noted in a comment, where the segmentation fault occurs. Nevertheless, I am entirely stumped. Would appreciate any help understanding the nature of this segmentation fault, thank you.

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{

    //create array of finite size (65536)
    int countArray[INT_MAX];

    //create array to eventually store sorted values
    int sortedValues[n];

    //loop through unsorted values to increment countArray index for each occurrence
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        countArray[ values[i] ] += 1;
    }


    //starting index for sortedValues[]
    int sortedIndex = 0;

    //loop until we've reached the end of sortedValues[]
    while(sortedIndex < n) {

        //loop through each index value of countArray
        //j represents the value
        for(int j = 0; j < INT_MAX; j++) {

            //how many times does the index of countArray occur in values[]?
            int c = countArray[j];

            //only add index j as a value to sortedValues[] if it appears in values[]
            while(c > 0) {

                //append j to sortedValues[]
                //--SEGMENTATION FAULT OCCURS ON THE LINE BELOW--
                sortedValues[sortedIndex] = j;

                //decrease the count of countArray[j] once value appended to sortedValues[]
                c -= 1;

                //move to next index of sortedValues[]
                sortedIndex += 1;
            }
        } 
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Check out the scope of some of the arrays based on where you've declared them.

Comment: You never initialised countArray. This can cause c to be anything. Which can cause sortedIndex to go to any value (including negative)

Comment: You cannot pass variable as size of an array as you have done in `int sortedValues[n];` you should allocate the array using `int* sortedValues = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);` and later use `free(sortedValues);` to free the allocated memory.

Comment: What is the point of assigning sortedValues in a loop if it is going to be assigned the same value?

Comment: You also have error in the logic of your program. You don't need a separate loop for `sortedIndex`.

Comment: Interesting, your comment indicates that you believe INT_MAX is 16 bits (and therefore sizeof(int) == 2)?  It's rare to come across that nowadays.

Comment: @BradBales OP probably means that the data passed into his function does not exceed 2^16. I thought the same thing when I saw this line, but then I thought that 16-bit `int`s are both negative and positive, so the logic is going to break.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Thanks...I just saw that he was using the macro INT_MAX, which will be set to the highest value of int as the "C" compiler will see it.  I just thought it curious that he's developing on a system that has a 16 bit int; I thought that I was the only one that still developed in that kind of environment (IBM 4690, well, Toshiba now) :)

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar C has support for Variable Length Arrays.

Comment: @BradBales 16-bit int is common in embedded processors. 100s million per year in 2016

Comment: @chux: Thanks - wow, I did not know that, I appreciate the info.

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone! Another error was the code would decrement variable c before incrementing variable sortedIndex, which means the function exited the loop (1) after setting the value of values[sortedIndex] but before (2) it moved to the next sortedIndex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize `countArray` elements to zero to fix the crash:

```
int countArray[INT_MAX] = {0};
```

However, your function is still useless, because it places sorted numbers into a local array that never makes it out of the function. In order to fix this, remove `sortedValues` array, and use the original `values` array for the output instead:

```
values[sortedIndex] = j;
```

Now the caller will see that the array he passed into your function comes back sorted.

**Note:** The outer loop `while(sortedIndex < n)` is harmless but useless, because the `for` loop guarantees that `sortedIndex` is exactly `n`. You should remove the `while` loop from your code.

Answer (score 1):

As I have commented earlier you don't need a separate loop for `sortedIndex`.

And as suggested by @dasblinkenlight you don't need to create a local array `sortedValue` to store the sorted values instead you can sort the array `values` in place.

Also, you need to initialize `countArray` with all zeros to avoid garbage values to be indexed.

Here is the code:

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    //create array of finite size (65536)
    int countArray[INT_MAX] = {0};

    //loop through unsorted values to increment countArray index for each occurrence
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        countArray[ values[i] ] += 1;
    }

    //starting index for sortedValues[]
    int sortedIndex = 0;

   //loop through each index value of countArray
   //j represents the value
   for(int j = 0; j < INT_MAX; j++) {

    //how many times does the index of countArray occur in values[]?
    int c = countArray[j];

    //only add index j as a value to sortedValues[] if it appears in values[]
    while(c > 0) {
     //append j to sortedValues[]
     values[sortedIndex] = j;

     //decrease the count of countArray[j] once value appended to sortedValues[]
     c -= 1;

     //move to next index of sortedValues[]
     sortedIndex += 1;
    }
   }
}
```